# Only one custom field been populated out of many

Tags: docusignapi

I have a document that I’d like to pre-populate.  In the document the person’s name is repeated multiple times so I’ve set up a text fields, given them the same label e.g. “CandidateName” and set them all to not required and read only.

The reason why all of them are set to read only is because I programmatically set them when I call DocuSign via API (TextTabs).  As result only the final field is populated.  All the previous ones are blank.

Cheers

Comment: Can you give more details as well as maybe a JSON extract or a piece of your current code ?

Comment: 1) I just draged and droped few text fields, added a datalabel of "CandidateName" to all of them.
2) sent it to API, these are my tabs:
private Tabs SetupPrePopulationFields(PackSetup model)
        {
            return new Tabs()
            {
                TextTabs = new List<Text>()
                {
                    new Text()
                    {
                        TabLabel = "FirstName",
                        Value = model.Candidate.FirstName
                    }
                }
            };
        }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your template contains multiple fields that have the same `tabLabel` and you want to populate all of those fields with the same value by using the API, you need to prefix the `tabLabel` value with `\\*`.

For example, here's the JSON for the `tabs` portion of a **CreateEnvelope** request that would populate every field which has the label **CandidateName** with the value **John Smith**.

```
"tabs": 
  { 
    "textTabs": [
        {
          "tabLabel": "\\*CandidateName",
          "value": "John Smith"
        }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: This was a lifesaver! For anyone looking for the documentation around this, you can find it [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/tabs#automatically-populating-tabs)